# SQL create identifiers based on conditions

Tags: sql

I have an SQL database and I have to identify certain 'groups' of rows based on an identifier.

Basically i have one column with another identifier and a column with time difference between the rows. The table is ordered by these values as show in this example:

| ID | timedifference |
| --- | --- |
| A | 21 |
| A | 30 |
| A | 60 |
| A | 50 |
| B | 32 |
| B | 120 |
| B | 20 |
| C | 124 |
| C | 10 |

I want to group the rows that belong together with the same identifier and use a clause so the identifier value changes when one of the following conditions are met:

- timedifference > 44 OR ID value is different from the previous row
  This should result in the following table:

| ID | timedifference | GroupID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 1 |
| A | 30 | 1 |
| A | 60 | 2 |
| A | 50 | 3 |
| B | 32 | 4 |
| B | 120 | 5 |
| B | 20 | 5 |
| C | 124 | 6 |
| C | 10 | 6 |

Comment: Hi and welcome ti the SO, what DB are you on? "The table is ordered by these values" - the DB stores table rows in no order, so you can't be sure it will be always stored in that order as in your example. Is there another column in the table to order line on? Like "create_date" or something?

Comment: _The table is ordered by these values_ no it isn't. Is there a column that contains the actual sort order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SQL Window Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) to access the preceding row.
However, you need to provide a rule on how to order the query results.
You say that

> Basically i have one column with another identifier and a column with time difference between the rows. The table is ordered by these values as show in this example

But - as pointed out by the comments - this is not the case in your example listing.

**Creating Order**

For this answer, I assume that there is well defined way to order the rows in your example: I added a column `item_order` to the table.

| id | time_difference | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 0 |
| A | 30 | 1 |
| A | 60 | 2 |
| A | 50 | 3 |
| B | 32 | 4 |
| B | 120 | 5 |
| B | 20 | 6 |
| C | 124 | 7 |
| C | 10 | 8 |

**Accessing Preceding Row**

*SQL Window Functions* let you access rows outside the current row of a query result: The `LAG()` window function gives you access the preceding row in your ordered result set (ie "Window"). The `OVER( ORDER BY item_order ASC )` defines this window and its order.

For instance

```
SELECT
    time_difference,
    LAG(time_difference, 1) OVER (ORDER BY item_order) AS "previous_row_time_difference",
    item_order
FROM test_table
ORDER BY item_order
```

Will result in

| time_difference | previous_row_time_difference | item_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | NULL | 0 |
| 30 | 21 | 1 |
| 60 | 30 | 2 |
| 50 | 60 | 3 |
| 32 | 50 | 4 |
| 120 | 32 | 5 |
| 20 | 120 | 6 |
| 124 | 20 | 7 |
| 10 | 124 | 8 |

**Comparing Current with Preceding Row**

You can use a SQL `CASE` statement to check if your condition is met:

```
SELECT id,
       time_difference,
       CASE
           WHEN LAG(id, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY item_order ASC) IS NULL -- this will be true in the very first row
                   OR LAG(id, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY item_order ASC) != id -- is the ID value different from the previous row
                   OR time_difference > 44 -- is time_difference bigger than 44
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
       END AS "has_different_group_from_preceding_row"
FROM test_table
ORDER BY item_order
```

This returns `1` in the `has_different_group_from_preceding_row` column for any row which meets your condition:

| id | time_difference | has_different_group_from_preceding_row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 1 |
| A | 30 | 0 |
| A | 60 | 1 |
| A | 50 | 1 |
| B | 32 | 1 |
| B | 120 | 1 |
| B | 20 | 0 |
| C | 124 | 1 |
| C | 10 | 0 |

**Create Group ID**

At last, we need to add the incrementing category counter in the `group_id` column. One option is to sum all the values from `has_different_group_from_preceding_row` which occur in previous rows.

For this we add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_order ASC) AS "row_num"` to the query above and turn it into a subquery using `WITH`.

```
-- create the subquery to detect all category changes
WITH detect_differene_between_rows AS(
    SELECT id,
           time_difference,
           CASE
               WHEN LAG(id, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY item_order ASC) IS NULL -- this will be true in the very first row
                       OR LAG(id, 1) OVER ( ORDER BY item_order ASC) != id -- is the ID value different from the previous row
                       OR time_difference > 44 -- is time_difference bigger than 44
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
           END AS "has_different_group_from_preceding_row",
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item_order ASC) AS "row_num" -- create the row number
    FROM test_table
    ORDER BY item_order
)

SELECT id, time_difference,
       -- another subquery to sum up the values of `has_difference_from_previous_row` from preceding rows
       (
           SELECT
               sum(has_different_group_from_preceding_row)
           FROM detect_differene_between_rows sdbr2
           WHERE sdbr2.row_num <= sdbr1.row_num
       ) AS "group_id"
FROM detect_differene_between_rows AS sdbr1;
```

| id | time_difference | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 1 |
| A | 30 | 1 |
| A | 60 | 2 |
| A | 50 | 3 |
| B | 32 | 4 |
| B | 120 | 5 |
| B | 20 | 5 |
| C | 124 | 6 |
| C | 10 | 6 |

**Further Considerations**

- **Updating `group_id` column:** The SQL query above does not update the `group_id` column of the original table: It is only a `SELECT`. Running an `UPDATE` on a table from a subquery on that very same table is tricky. There is a way to update a table from a join, but this requires a primary key to match rows in the join. One workaround would be to create a temporary table and `INSERT` records from the `SELECT` above.
- **Performance:** The summation from preceding rows will be time consuming. I assume that the `group_id` is populated once only. *Windows Functions* are part of the SQL standard and should be supported across most DBs. But I would not be surprised if other SQL dialects have a more performant way to solve this problem.
- **Column Naming:** The column name `ID` (or "`id`") is usually the primary key of a table. In this example, the `ID` column is used for something that is more like a category ('A', 'B', etc). I would change the same accordingly. Otherwise this may cause issues for developers as they will assume that `ID` is a unique identifier for each row/record.